# SQL Server Backup error - not part of a multiple family media set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

I am trying to backup my SQL Server 2008 R2 database. However I am getting the below error, no matter where I try to save the backup.

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The volume on device 'D:\Programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\dbName.bak'
>   is not part of a multiple family media set. BACKUP WITH FORMAT can be
>   used to form a new media set. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo).*

Can anyone throw light on this?

The only helpful links I could google were following but of little use:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/a1eb2818-2a97-4c52-aa8d-7c224f1ac282

and

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic279584-24-1.aspx

Comment: Could you include some details on how do you restore it? The exact command would be best.

Comment: I just used the backup wizard. not the query.

Comment: Once you've set all the settings, please click *Script* button at the top and it should give you the query.

Comment: BACKUP DATABASE [dbname] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'<dbname>-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO

Comment: What happens if you try `WITH FORMAT`? As in *Options* - *Back up to a new media set and erase all existing backup sets*  option in the GUI.

Comment: Huuraay..this worked..Thanks a ton Serge!!!

Comment: Great to know that =) I've posted this as an answer to complete the story.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue however, here's a workaround for whoever might run into this: use `WITH FORMAT` clause or *Options - Back up to a new media set and erase all existing backup sets option in the GUI*.